# bxslider overflowing page in Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, bxslider

The problem with the bxslider in Firefox is overflow. If you click a category page, no problem, but if you click the homepage icon/logo, images in bxslider exceed the width and the bxslider overflows the page.

Here is the [link](http://www.magazagsstore.com/)

Comment: @MarsOne congrats for understanding the original question

Comment: Lol. Thanks. Was a bit of a struggle